# Setting off a workflow action when a form view is submitted

Tags: workflow, infopath, approval-process

I have an InfoPath form with two views. When the first view is submitted a Nintex WorkFlow kicks in and an Approval is sent to Manager A. If Manager A approves and email is sent to the form initiator asking them to fill in the second view.

What I want to happen is that when the initiator then submits the second view that Manager B then gets an approval request to approve.

What's currently happening is that the initiator gets the email to fill in the second view an email to being sent to Manager B at the same time, before the initiator has actually submitted the second view.

I think I need a logic action and I've put a Filter in checking that a field in view two is either pass or fail before moving onto the Approval task for Manager B, but what's happening is upon submission it's just going back to the first stage of the Workflow.

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a Status column with values similar to

- Submitted by View 1
- Approved by Manager A
- Declined by Manager A
- Submitted by View 2
- Approved by Manager B
- Declined by Manager B

In InfoPath view 1, set the hidden "Status" field value with "Submitted by View 1". Same for view 2, set "Submitted by View 2".

In your Nintex workflow, create a switch action on Statuses "Submitted by View 1" and "Submitted by View 2" and send approval notifications to Manager A and Manager B respectively.

With these settings, the workflow will send approval email to Manager A when view 1 is submitted and to Manager B when view 2 is submitted.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I does and it doesn't. What I need to happen is that the Approver gets a notification of a task AFTER the form initiator has submitted View 2. I don't think this approach will achieve that?